# Disable AVX instructions for entire catkin workspace

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a multitude of packages in my catkin workspace that all need to be compiled without using AVX instructions. Is there a way to globally disable AVX instructions when using `catkin build`? It is not an option for me to disable AVX instructions in every single CMakeLists.txt.

My first attempt was to add `-mavx` to the Make Args of `catkin config` but that was unsuccessful probably because it is not a Make argument but a compiler option.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252886/disable-avx-instructions-for-entire-catkin-workspace/) by [MrX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25166/mrx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This works:

```
catkin build --force-cmake --cmake-args -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-mno-avx"
```

---

Originally posted by [MrX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25166/mrx/) with karma: 20 on 2017-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0